# Regex with stringr:: how to find first instance of pattern

Tags: regex, r, latex, knitr, stringr

Behind this question is an effort to extract all references created by `knitr` and `latex`.  Not finding another way, my thought was to read into R the .Rnw script and use a regular expression to find references -- where the latex syntax is `\ref{caption referenced to}`.  My script has 250+ references, and some are very close to each other.

The text.1 example below works, but not the text example.  I think it has to do with R chugging along to the final closing brace.  How do I stop at the first closing brace and extract what preceded it to the opening brace?

```
library(stringr)
text.1 <- c(" \\ref{test}", "abc", "\\ref{test2}", " \\section{test3}", "{test3")
# In the regular expression below, look back and if find "ref{", grab everything until look behind for } at end
# braces are special characters and require escaping with double backslacs for R to recognize them as braces
# unlist converts the list returned by str_extract to a vector

unlist(str_extract_all(string = text.1, pattern = "(?<=ref\\{).*(?=\\}$)"))
[1] "test"  "test2"

# a more complicated string, with more than one set of braces in an element
text <- c("text \ref{?bar labels precision} and more text  \ref{?table column alignment}", "text \ref{?table space} }")

unlist(str_extract_all(string = text, pattern = "(?<=ref\\{).*(?=\\}$)"))
character(0)
```

Comment: @stribizhev, no, I hadn't tried them.  But I did just now and they both return character (0).  Thanks for the question.  And, there are no nested situations, only one after another sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `text` is the backslash in front of "ref" is being interpreted as a carriage return `\r` by the engine and R's parser; so you're trying to match "ref" but it's really (`CR` <kbd>+</kbd> "ef") ...

Also `*` is **greedy** by default, meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `*?` or a negated character class to prevent greediness.

```
unlist(str_extract_all(text, '(?<=\ref\\{)[^}]*'))
# [1] "?bar labels precision"   "?table column alignment" "?table space"
```

As you can see, you can use a character class to match either (`\r` or `r` <kbd>+</kbd> "ef") ...

```
x <- c(' \\ref{test}', 'abc', '\\ref{test2}', ' \\section{test3}', '{test3',
       'text \ref{?bar labels precision} and more text  \ref{?table column alignment}', 
       'text \ref{?table space} }')

unlist(str_extract_all(x, '(?<=[\rr]ef\\{)[^}]*'))

# [1] "test"                    "test2"                   "?bar labels precision"  
# [4] "?table column alignment" "?table space"
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

The reason why it didn't capture what is before the closing brace `}` is because you added an end of line anchor `$`. Remove `$` and it would work.

Therefore, you new code should be like this

```
 unlist(str_extract_all(string = text, pattern = "(?<=ref\\{)[^}]*(?=\\})"))
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD8wO2/7)

Comment: IMO `text.1` was already supported by the OP, the problem is with `text`.

Comment: @daroczig is correct.  Thank you, james, but My problem is with more complex strings.  Removing the end of line anchor does not solve text.

Comment: The edited post would work for complex strings. Check out the demo

Comment: @daroczig. Thanks for the correction. The link and the pattern has been edited. It should work now

Comment: Sorry, is the demo code what you propose or the edited answer.  I can seem to get either to work on text.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `(?<=ref\\{)[^}]*(?=\\})`